# Nested if else statments

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, trading

I am relatively new to R and I am trying to analyze trading data for all of my trades. Currently I am having some trouble when attempting to tie multiple "if else" statements together that have two conditions I am checking for. Essentially, what I am trying to do is look into a data frame, look at one column which is the year column, check if that column is the year 2005 and check if trades for that year are less than or equal to month 6. If it is I want to create a new column that tags those to a period 2005(1) and 2005(2) respectively. Once that if else is complete I want the next line of code to run to check for 2006, 2007 2008...2018 and tag those years. I am not sure if I should be using a for loop, while loop, or if there is an easier way to run my code to run in sequential order without overwriting the previous expression. Would appreciate any help/advice anyone could give me.

Code:

```
FilteredEURAUDTrades$TradingPeriod<- ifelse(
   (
       (FilteredEURAUDTrades$Year %in% c(2005)) &
         (FilteredEURAUDTrades$Month <=6)  
   ),
 "2005(1)",
 "2005(2)"
   )


FilteredEURAUDTrades$TradingPeriod<- ifelse(
   (
     (FilteredEURAUDTrades$Year %in% c(2006)) &
       (FilteredEURAUDTrades$Month <=6)  
   ),
   "2006(1)",
   "2006(2)"
 )



FilteredEURAUDTrades$TradingPeriod<- ifelse(
  (
    (FilteredEURAUDTrades$Year %in% c(2007)) &
      (FilteredEURAUDTrades$Month <=6)  
  ),
  "2007(1)",
  "2007(2)"
)
```

**[Trying to connect one if else statement to another if else statement in sequential order, paste results into a new column in a data frame.]**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`FilteredEURAUDTrades$TradingPeriod <- paste0(FilteredEURAUDTrades$Year, "(", FilteredEURAUDTrades$Month %/% 7 + 1, ")")`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help David!

Comment: No problem, just remember to vote up the response when you get a chance.

Comment: Definitely will do! Thanks again!